# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column `last field` in INSERT Query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having an strange problem with a MySQL insert. It can't find the last field, no matter what it's name is:

```
insert into
    `exams` (`abbr`, `due_days`, `name`, `section_id`, `id`)
values
    ('PT', 1, 'PT - TIEMPO DE PROTROMBINA.', 2, 129);
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `exams` (`abbr`, `due_days`, `name`, `section_id`, `id`) values (PT, 1, PT - TIEMPO DE PROTROMBINA., 2, 129)
```

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `exams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `abbr` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `due_days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

- The fun fact here is that this `id` column exists, but MySQL can't find It.
- I tried to rename it, but it didn't work
- I tried to remove the backtick and it works but only in console, in my PHP query builder It doesn't work
- I tried to delete this field but then I notice this extrange behaviour:

---

```
insert into
    `exams` (`abbr`, `due_days`, `name`, `section_id`)
values
    ('PT', 1, 'PT - TIEMPO DE PROTROMBINA.', 2);
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'section_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `exams` (`abbr`, `due_days`, `name`, `section_id`) values (PT, 1, PT - TIEMPO DE PROTROMBINA., 2)
```

Again the last column have an error...
I tested in both MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 10.0 in different machines but I got the exact result.

---

I'm using Laravel 5 and I even could remove the backticks from the query builder, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Silly question, but have you selected the correct database?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not simply using a model and the save() method?

Comment: @Darren yeah man, I make sure :)

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using `$Model::insert()`, I'm importing data from a CSV file but the problem isn't Laravel related, is more like a MySQL problem

Comment: @MarkBaker I also try with `$Model::create()` and `DB::table($table)->insert()` =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you copied and past your query (or part of query) from some PDF or somewhere else, I tried it on my own system, when I copied query from your question I was getting error as you are getting (I guess their were some unprintable code-Unicode chars, those are not visible). Then I re-write query by hand and it worked! check below:

[image]

Note: I didn't change your create query. Just copied pasted from your question at my MySQL interpreter.

Re-write your query by hand it works! I just edited `id\`) and double quoted strings.

[image]

Give it a Try!!

Comment: for me too,I tried with manual typing, no error, there is difference between **`** and **'** +1

Comment: Yep, you're right... But those are queries generated by Laravel, so there is no recommended way to do it. The queries in my question are just for reference. I also remove the ``` from the Laravel Query Builder, so the query was `insert into exams (abbr, due_days, ..., id) values ('PT'...` but I keep getting the same error =(

Comment: I got interested in your answer, let me dig a little more ;)

Answer (score 2):

id is the primary key it has to have a value when you insert, perhaps it should be defaulted to auto increment

simply change:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

to:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, my `id` field isn't AI. Is s simple integer field

Comment: then you have to add a  value for `id`, as the key cant be empty

Comment: You're right but I even make an `id PK AI` and just rename this `id` to `exam_id` and this was failing again. I remove the `_id` but nothing... And every field has its values, no one is empty =(

Comment: im not sure if your saying its fixed or not

Comment: Nope, I tried that before making this question =) ---- My english sucks, sorry

Comment: Sure, I'm really confused about this too, I know that it should work... But it doesn't

Comment: copy and paste from the fiddle, soemting in your code does not match up.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got it. It was a problem with the encoding of my file. =P